# What does 'thrust up the trap' mean in context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'thrust up the trap' mean in context?

> At Thirty-fourth Street young Richard quickly **thrust up the trap** and
>   ordered the cabman to stop.

Mammon and the Archer
by O. Henry

Answer (score 2):

It may refer to a sliding window in the cab that separates the passenger compartment from the driver for privacy. It would have to be slid aside to talk to the cab driver.

Here is a definition of "trapdoor" that may fit:
[American Heritage Dictionary "trapdoor"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=trapdoor)
"A hinged or sliding door in a floor, roof, or ceiling."

In this case, it would be a sliding door in the compartment separator.

Here is a description of such a door in a horse-drawn cab:
[Wikipedia "hansom cab" design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansom_cab)
"The passengers could give their instructions to the driver through a trap door near the rear of the roof."